# How can i convert this query(postgresql) to laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I want to convert below `postgresql` code to laravel `eloquent`

```
select s2.itemdesc,
       to_char(date_trunc('month', saledate), 'YYYY') AS year,
       to_char(date_trunc('month', saledate), 'Month') AS month,
       to_char(date_trunc('month', saledate), 'MM') AS month_number,
       sum(qty) AS qty1
from sale s left join saled s2 on s.saleno = s2.saleno 
GROUP BY s2.itemdesc, date_trunc('month', saledate)
order by s2.itemdesc desc and month desc
```

I have tried query in Postgresql Manager and its work. but I failed when convert to Laravel `eloquent`

Comment: reconsider update your question, add your `eloquent` code or some `error` that happen when running your code, so the audience know, whats your specific problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DB::query()` returns an instance of the query builder.

From that instance, you can list the columns you want to select as comma separated parameters with `select()`.
For computed or aggregated columns, passing `DB::raw(expression)` instead of the raw expression works. Another way is to pass everything as a single parameter to `selectRaw` is also an option.

There are two ways to select the main table: The Query Builder's `from(table, alias)` method. The alias parameter is optional. The table parameter can be either a string or a Closure for subquery tables. `DB::table(table, alias)` also works. It's functionally the same as doing `DB::query()->from(table, alias)`.

`groupBy()`/`groupByRaw()` is used to group by columns.

`orderBy()`/`orderByRaw()` is used to order by columns.

```php
DB::query()
    ->select(
        's2.itemdesc',
        DB::raw("to_char(date_trunc('month', saledate), 'YYYY') AS year"),
        DB::raw("to_char(date_trunc('month', saledate), 'Month') AS month"),
        DB::raw("to_char(date_trunc('month', saledate), 'MM') AS month_number"),
        DB::raw("sum(qty) AS qty1")
    )
    ->from('sale', 's')
    ->leftJoin('saled s2', 's.saleno', 's2.saleno')
    ->groupByRaw("s2.itemdesc, date_trunc('month', saledate)")
    ->orderByRaw("s2.itemdesc desc, month desc")
    ->get();
```

An Eloquent Model works the same way.

```php
Sale::query()->...
```

Comment: Your Explanation are quite easy to understand too, it's great to improve my knowledge :)